# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using `Visual Studio 2010` with `Crystal Report`. It is working fine in my local server but on web server, it is giving error :
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name`.
I tried many solutions like put `.rpt` file in any folder and provide that path, give full permission to windows temp folder, enable parent path form IIS etc.
But none of them is working. Please help me to solve this.

**My current path :**

```
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PurchaseOrder1.rpt"));
```

[image: Crystal Report error]

Comment: What does Server.MapPath("~/PurchaseOrder1.rpt") return? Is it the correct location to the file?  Also have you given IIS_IUSERS access to the file through NTFS?

Comment: @John, Server.MapPath is correct, It is working fine on local server. Let me check for IIS_IUSERS permission.

Comment: Same error even after giving IIS_IUSERS permission.

Comment: @John, when I try to access `website/PurchaseOrder1.rpt` path directly, it gives 404 error on server.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with file/folder permissions. Don't think it will display the rpt file through the website as it does not have mime type for it.  Maybe give the everyone group all permissions to the file/folder to see if that works, then we can work backwards.

Comment: Maybe this is a solution?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283978/crystal-report-invalid-file-name-issue)

Comment: You've tried specifying a full path then? `@"C:\SomeFolder\PurchaseOrder1.rpt"`. Also, if you do a simple `File.Exists` on the PurchaseOrder1.rpt, does it return true?

Answer (score 2):

Not a whole answer but I'm too new to SO just to comment.  One thing you could try is to download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and watch to see where Crystal is trying to load the file from and that may help.  Process Monitor will give a lot of output but that can be filtered on, for instance, part of the filename.  It may tell you if there is a permissions issue too.  I find it very useful for these sort of situations where you can't work out why a file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the culprit may be a trailing `/` on the Webserver path.

Try using `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "PurchaseOrder1.rpt");`

This should put appropriate `/` in the path and might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main difference with local and server environment is IIS root and the virtual directory that your application is located.

I mean, if the file is in the root of the site, you might want to use

`crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("/PurchaseOrder1.rpt"));`

OR you can try putting the rpt file into the same folder with `ViewPurchaseOrder.aspx` without changing the code

If it doesn't work, if you could share paths (both physical and virtual) we can check further.

*Edit: When using Server.MapPath

`/` returns site root

`~/` returns root directory of the application

The difference is that if your site is:

http://yoursite.com
And you have an application that's on `wwwroot\somedir\app`

So in your "app" (http://yoursite.com/somedir/app)

/ should return the root of the site (http://yoursite.com)

~/ should return the root of the application (http://yoursite.com/somedir/)